# Is it common to use POCOs and model binding to do contextual validation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I've noticed in ASP.NET MVC, it's commonplace to use model binding and validation annotations in conjunction with business objects that also interact with the database.

Unfortunately, this means that the scope of the request and the validation taking place must always be 1:1 with domain models.  At the very least not without having to code a bunch of exceptions.

If I'm looking for a way to do contextual validation in ASP.NET MVC, are there any examples of or is it an accepted practice already to use POCO classes that represent the incoming data?

Let's say I call these "Request Models". An example might be that I create a class called `UpdateUserRequestModel`.  I define only the data that I allow for a user update, then, I have MVC bind the values into this surrogate model. Later in my controller/services, I access the request model's public properties for the values I wish to move over to the user object.

So, the question here is: Is there already any example of this practice in commonly accepted ASP.NET MVC conventions?  Does it have a particular name?  Failing that, when I wish to do contextual validation, are there any better options than the default model binders and value providers that MVC ships with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it on my apps. I validate actions the user performs, putting validation attributes etc on that view model that represents that action (conveniently models the form in the view and model binds the result on the way back). I even ported the ContosoUniversity app to reflect this style:

https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversity